# Disable links to parent menus and breadcrumbs?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

1) can I disable links of parents items in Drupal menus ? (In particular if I'm using the Nice Menu module ? I don't have any page to link to the parent items.

2) can I disable the links on the breadcrumbs ? I guess I have to change the php code for that.

thanks

Comment: 1. what are you trying to keep people from doing? can you give an example of what this menu will look and work like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [Special menu items](https://www.drupal.org/project/special_menu_items) module. Some more details about this module (from its project page):

> Special menu items is a Drupal module that provides placeholder and separator menu items.
>
> A placeholder is a menu item which is not a link. It is useful with dynamic drop down menus where we want to have a parent menu item which is not linking to a page but just acting as a parent grouping some menu items below it.
>
> A separator menu item is something like "-------" which is not linking anywhere but merely a mean to structure menus and "separate" menu items visually.

Answer (score 0):

#2. you can create a new breadcrumb.tpl.php file in your theme that removes the links and only has the text.

Comment: I cannot find the original file breadcrumb.tpl.php to copy the original php from... where is it ? I need the template, I cannot start from scratch

Answer (score 0):

From http://drupal.org/node/143322#comment-2284294, you can override theme_menu_item_link to accomplish this:

```
function yourthemename_menu_item_link($link) {
  if (empty($link['localized_options'])) {
    $link['localized_options'] = array();
  }
    if ($link['type'] && $link['has_children']) {
    return ''.check_plain($link['title']).'';
  }
    return l($link['title'], $link['href'], $link['localized_options']);
}
```